# Gitlab runner documentation about docker executor is ambiguous, how do you add a private ssh key?

Tags: docker, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

The [gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#ssh-keys-when-using-the-docker-executor) has the following description for the variable `$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY`:

> Create a new file type CI/CD variable. As Key enter the name
> SSH_PRIVATE_KEY and in the Value field paste the content of your
> private key that you created earlier.

Which according to my understanding means that I am supposed to paste the contents of my
`~/.ssh/id_ed25519` file there.

In their `gitlab-ci.yaml`, they say

```
  - chmod 400 "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"
  - ssh-add "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"
```

But if `$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` is the contents of a generated private key (starting with `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----` etc.), this obviously fails. What exactly am I supposed to plac in the `$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` variable if not my private key?

Comment: What is the error that it is failing with?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Type of the Variable, that was added in Admin > Settings > CI/CD.  If the key Type = Variable (usually default), then [use something like this](https://dev.to/atdigitals/build-and-deploy-react-using-gitlab-ci-pipeline-2bhc):

```
 - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
```

It can also be set to Type = File, in which case the commands shown in [gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/) is the way to add the SSH key. You may notice that the document specifically mentions adding "file type CI/CD variable".